# Zend Framework (PHPUnit) Tests won'r run (phpunit: command not found / Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found)

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit, command-line-interface, zend-test

i installed PHPUnit by the book:

```
sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
sudo pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
```

The include path is added in the `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`

```
include_path = ".:/usr/share/php"

$ ls /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/
Extensions  Framework
```

But now, if I want to run the Tests for Zend Framework

```
user@server:/var/www/page/tests$ ./runtests.sh 
+ phpunit --verbose AllTests
./runtests.sh: line 72: phpunit: command not found
user@server:/var/www/page/tests$ php AllTests.php 
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found in /var/www/page/tests/Zend/Acl/AclTest.php on line 37
```

Of course i also get a `phpunit: command not found`when i try to follow the instructions in the PHPUnit Manual http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html outside of Zend Framework Context.

I'm getting the Feeling I'm missing something essential here ...

**Solved**

Looks like there was a Problem with the PEAR Channels, after adding the other 2 Again, it worked:

```
pear channel-discover components.ez.no
pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
```

Comment: Do you have path to the folder containing phpunit in you PATH variable?

Comment: @marcin could you please be a little bit more specific?

Comment: @Hannes. phpunit is a command that can be executed from your terminal. try setting it, i.e. export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/folder/with/phpunit

Comment: @Marcin I did `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/share/php/PHPUnit` nothing changed , but as you see above, in the Folger `/usr/share/php/PHPUnit` are only 2 sub direcotrys, nothing really to be executed

Comment: @Hannes. So maybe phpunit is in other folder or your phpunit was not fully installed if this command is missing.

Comment: @Marcin - I used find and only found `/usr/share/php/PHPUnit` as an appropriate match - But after Reinstalling the Whole thing it seems to work now - thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the problem was solved in the comments I just make a real answer to sum up.

The reason for the problem was missing phpunit command. Reinstallation of phpunit and setting variable PATH to the folder containing phpunit command (`export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/folder/with/phpunit`) solved the issue.